# NSJSONSerialization and Emoji

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdata, nsjsonserialization, emoji

I'm currently trying to POST some JSON containing emojis to a python API. I tried feeding the *NSJSONSerialization* directly with the string containing the emojis from my *UITextField* but the serializer crashed with no meaningful explanation.
Afterwards I tried to do some format conversion and ended up with something like this:

```
NSString *uniText = mytextField.text;
NSData *msgData = [uniText dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *goodMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:msgData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

This basically works except that the resulting UTF-8 is kinda double-"escaped" resulting in the following:

```
"title":"\\ud83d\\udc8f\\ud83d\\udc8f\\ud83d\\udc8f\\ud83d"
```

Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: NSJSONSerialization should work.

Comment: I thought that is exactly what `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` was supposed to do.

Comment: JSON should ALWAYS be UTF.

Comment: uniText contains the text that you want. goodMsg contains the text in some messed up format. NSJSONSerialization would have serialized uniText perfectly well, instead you asked it to serialize your messed up "goodMsg".

Comment: No. I tried inputting it directly but it just SIGABRTs, no exception printed, exception breakpoint also doing nothing >.<

Comment: You're encoding the string using one encoding and trying to decode the result using a different encoding! That's probably not what you meant to do.

Comment: Do not use `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` use `NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding`. emoji are in UTF Plane 1 and thus are 21 bit code points.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion @Zaph but I get a nil data :(

Comment: so what can I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: See my answer example code, I didn't use your unicode characters, can you post, copy and paste, the emoji characters. Or in your code change `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` to `NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding`, run the code and post the output.

Comment: (NSString *) uniText = 0x1680e0a0 @""

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. If I copy and paste your code everything seems to work fine, only when I try to use my text field everything goes berserk... any ideas?

Comment: Log what is coming back from the text field: `NSLog(@"uniText utf-32: %@", [uniText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding]);` and post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two difficulties:
 1. Apple hosed `NSString` WRT UTF Planes 1 and above, the underlying use
    of UTF-16 shows through. An example is that `length` will return 2 for
    one emoji character.
 2. Whoever decided to put emoji in Plane 1 was
    just being difficult, it is the first use of Plane 1 and a lot of
    legacy UTF code does not handle that correctly.

Example code (adapted from @Hot Licks):
Updated with OP emoji

```
NSString *uniText = @"";
NSDictionary* jsonDict = @{@"title":uniText};

NSData * utf32Data = [uniText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"utf32Data: %@", utf32Data);

NSError* error = nil;
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&error];
if (jsonData == nil) {
    NSLog(@"JSON serialization error: %@", error);
}
else {
    NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"The JSON result is %@", jsonString);
    NSLog(@"jsonData: %@", jsonData);
}
```

NSLog output

> utf32Data: a6f40100 8ff40100 52f40100 52f40100 a6f40100
>   The JSON result is {"title":""}
>   jsonData: 7b227469 746c6522 3a22f09f 92a6f09f 928ff09f 9192f09f 9192f09f 92a6227d

Answer (score 0):

Sigh:

```
NSString* uniText = mytextField.text;
NSDictionary* jsonDict = @{@"title":uniText};
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJsonObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&error];
if (jsonData == nil) {
    NSLog(@"JSON serialization error: %@", error);
}
else {
    NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"The JSON result is %@", jsonString);
}
```

If myTextField.text is a valid NSString then no other conversions should be required.  NSJSONSerialization will provide all necessary "escaping".

Comment: I already tried that. I really just copy pasted your code and the line where the serialization to NSData happens just crashes with SIGABRT. No useful exception, setting an exceptions breakpoint also provides no further results ...

Comment: I fixed them, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to compile it obviously ...NSString* text = metadata[@"title"];
    NSDictionary* jsonDict = @{@"title":text};
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&error];
    if (jsonData == nil) {
        NSLog(@"JSON serialization error: %@", error);
    }
    else {
        NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"The JSON result is %@", jsonString);
    }

Comment: @TimSpecht What about Hot Licks' answer is different from Zaph's?