# NSJSONSerialization not working with emoji

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, nsjsonserialization

and i want to get values out of this.

**String**

> "[{\"VisitorId\":\"dbd1c1d6-8348-4674-9e48-65137bdc5c14\",\"OperatorID\":null,\"VisitorSignalId\":\"6c454fc2-cf74-4010-aecd-93d93408ad24\",\"Type\":\"Visitor\",\"Messagetext\":\"ksksksksksk
>   has joined the chat!\",\"IsJoin\":true,\"MessageTime\":\"2017-02-07
>   05:10:28\",\"File\":null,\"MessageType\":\"JoinMessage\",\"Name\":\"ksksksksksk\",\"Email\":\"skdsm@fdg.com\",\"IP\":\"123.231.110.188\",\"Page\":\"http://www.sathyabaman.com/\",\"Rating\":\"No Rating\",\"Image\":null,\"CurrentOpImage\":null,\"FileUploadDetails\":null,\"FirstOperatorName\":null,\"OperatorCount\":1,\"RequestTranscript\":false,\"Country\":null,\"OS\":null,\"Broswer\":null,\"Mobile\":null,\"iso_code\":null},{\"VisitorId\":\"dbd1c1d6-8348-4674-9e48-65137bdc5c14\",\"OperatorID\":null,\"VisitorSignalId\":null,\"Type\":\"Visitor\",\"Messagetext\":\"lkkhnl\",\"IsJoin\":false,\"MessageTime\":\"2017-02-07
>   05:10:58\",\"File\":null,\"MessageType\":\"NormalMessage\",\"Name\":\"ksksksksksk\",\"Email\":\"skdsm@fdg.com\",\"IP\":\"123.231.110.188\",\"Page\":\"http://www.sathyabaman.com/\",\"Rating\":\"No Rating\",\"Image\":null,\"CurrentOpImage\":null,\"FileUploadDetails\":null,\"FirstOperatorName\":null,\"OperatorCount\":1,\"RequestTranscript\":false,\"Country\":null,\"OS\":null,\"Broswer\":null,\"Mobile\":null,\"iso_code\":null},{\"VisitorId\":null,\"OperatorID\":\"81aebba9-ddc3-4f58-b1af-ac912d23a41e\",\"VisitorSignalId\":null,\"Type\":\"Operator\",\"Messagetext\":\"how
>   can i help you today?\",\"IsJoin\":false,\"MessageTime\":\"2017-02-07
>   10:41:11\",\"File\":null,\"MessageType\":\"NormalMessage\",\"Name\":\"sathya\",\"Email\":null,\"IP\":null,\"Page\":null,\"Rating\":null,\"Image\":null,\"CurrentOpImage\":null,\"FileUploadDetails\":null,\"FirstOperatorName\":\"sathya\",\"OperatorCount\":1,\"RequestTranscript\":null,\"Country\":null,\"OS\":null,\"Broswer\":null,\"Mobile\":null,\"iso_code\":null},{\"VisitorId\":\"dbd1c1d6-8348-4674-9e48-65137bdc5c14\",\"OperatorID\":null,\"VisitorSignalId\":\"6c454fc2-cf74-4010-aecd-93d93408ad24\",\"Type\":\"Visitor\",\"Messagetext\":\"Visitor
>   is no longer active\",\"IsJoin\":false,\"MessageTime\":\"2/7/2017
>   5:11:53
>   AM\",\"File\":null,\"MessageType\":\"TransferMessage\",\"Name\":\"ksksksksksk\",\"Email\":\"skdsm@fdg.com\",\"IP\":\"123.231.110.188\",\"Page\":\"http://www.sathyabaman.com/\",\"Rating\":\"No Rating\",\"Image\":null,\"CurrentOpImage\":null,\"FileUploadDetails\":null,\"FirstOperatorName\":null,\"OperatorCount\":1,\"RequestTranscript\":false,\"Country\":null,\"OS\":null,\"Broswer\":null,\"Mobile\":null,\"iso_code\":null},{\"VisitorId\":null,\"OperatorID\":\"81aebba9-ddc3-4f58-b1af-ac912d23a41e\",\"VisitorSignalId\":null,\"Type\":\"Operator\",\"Messagetext\":\"Hi\",\"IsJoin\":false,\"MessageTime\":\"2017-02-07
>   10:47:54\",\"File\":null,\"MessageType\":\"NormalMessage\",\"Name\":\"sathya\",\"Email\":null,\"IP\":null,\"Page\":null,\"Rating\":null,\"Image\":null,\"CurrentOpImage\":null,\"FileUploadDetails\":null,\"FirstOperatorName\":\"sathya\",\"OperatorCount\":1,\"RequestTranscript\":null,\"Country\":null,\"OS\":null,\"Broswer\":null,\"Mobile\":null,\"iso_code\":null},{\"VisitorId\":null,\"OperatorID\":\"81aebba9-ddc3-4f58-b1af-ac912d23a41e\",\"VisitorSignalId\":null,\"Type\":\"Operator\",\"Messagetext\":\"how
>   can i help you today?\",\"IsJoin\":false,\"MessageTime\":\"2017-02-07
>   10:50:07\",\"File\":null,\"MessageType\":\"NormalMessage\",\"Name\":\"sathya\",\"Email\":null,\"IP\":null,\"Page\":null,\"Rating\":null,\"Image\":null,\"CurrentOpImage\":null,\"FileUploadDetails\":null,\"FirstOperatorName\":\"sathya\",\"OperatorCount\":1,\"RequestTranscript\":null,\"Country\":null,\"OS\":null,\"Broswer\":null,\"Mobile\":null,\"iso_code\":null},{\"VisitorId\":null,\"OperatorID\":\"81aebba9-ddc3-4f58-b1af-ac912d23a41e\",\"VisitorSignalId\":null,\"Type\":\"Operator\",\"Messagetext\":\"\",\"IsJoin\":false,\"MessageTime\":\"2017-02-07
>   10:57:13\",\"File\":null,\"MessageType\":\"NormalMessage\",\"Name\":\"sathya\",\"Email\":null,\"IP\":null,\"Page\":null,\"Rating\":null,\"Image\":null,\"CurrentOpImage\":null,\"FileUploadDetails\":null,\"FirstOperatorName\":\"sathya\",\"OperatorCount\":1,\"RequestTranscript\":null,\"Country\":null,\"OS\":null,\"Broswer\":null,\"Mobile\":null,\"iso_code\":null}]"

**Method**

```
+ (void) showCurrentHistory:(NSString *) historyString {

    NSString* processed = [historyString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"\""];

    NSString* withotExtras =  [[processed substringFromIndex:1] substringToIndex:[processed length] - 2];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:[withotExtras UTF8String] length:withotExtras.length];
    NSError *error;

    NSMutableArray* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    for (NSDictionary *dic in jsonArray) {
        NSString *VisitorId         = [dic objectForKey:@"VisitorId"];
        NSString *VisitorSignalId   = [dic objectForKey:@"VisitorSignalId"];
        NSString *Type              = [dic objectForKey:@"Type"];
        NSString *Messagetext       = [dic objectForKey:@"Messagetext"];
        NSString *MessageType       = [dic objectForKey:@"MessageType"];
        NSString *MessageTime       = [dic objectForKey:@"MessageTime"];
        NSString *Image             = [dic objectForKey:@"Image"];
        NSString *FileUploadDetails = [dic objectForKey:@"FileUploadDetails"];
        NSString *FirstOperatorName = [dic objectForKey:@"FirstOperatorName"];
        NSString *Rating            = [dic objectForKey:@"Rating"];

        NSLog(@"----------------------- Current  Chat History --------------------------------");
        NSLog(@"VisitorId           : %@" , VisitorId);
        NSLog(@"VisitorSignalId     : %@" , VisitorSignalId);
        NSLog(@"Type                : %@" , Type);
        NSLog(@"Messagetext         : %@" , Messagetext);
        NSLog(@"MessageType         : %@" , MessageType);
        NSLog(@"MessageTime         : %@" , MessageTime);
        NSLog(@"Image               : %@" , Image);
        NSLog(@"FileUploadDetails   : %@" , FileUploadDetails);
        NSLog(@"FirstOperatorName   : %@" , FirstOperatorName);
        NSLog(@"Rating              : %@" , Rating);
        NSLog(@"------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        MessageItemObject *item = [[MessageItemObject alloc] init];
        [item setVisitorId:VisitorId];
        [item setVisitorSignalId:VisitorSignalId];
        [item setType:Type];
        [item setMessagetext:Messagetext];
        [item setMessageType:MessageType];
        [item setMessageTime:MessageTime];
        [item setImage:Image];
        [item setFileUploadDetails:FileUploadDetails];
        [item setFirstOperatorName:FirstOperatorName];
        [item setRating:Rating];

        if (messagesList.count == 0) {
            messagesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [messagesList addObject:item];

            NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [dic setValue:@"Adding new chatting" forKey:@"Adding new Chatting"];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
             postNotificationName:@"PassData"
             object:nil
             userInfo:dic];
        } else {
            [messagesList addObject:item];

            NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [dic setValue:@"Adding new chatting" forKey:@"Adding new Chatting"];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
             postNotificationName:@"PassData"
             object:nil
             userInfo:dic];
        }
    }
}
```

This method works fine if there is no emoji, since this sting has a single \ emoji , NSJSONSerialization is not working. Can some one help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814394/nsjsonserialization-and-emoji

Comment: You need to replace that "Two Hear emoji"  with blank string if you are not going to use it. OR replace it with its unicode.

Comment: @User511 that worked TNX.

Comment: I don't see idk he is getting his solution in that. Why the answer gets deleted?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are hardcoding the JSON string and making changes on it, don't do make any changes with your `JSON` string and directly convert it to `NSData`.

```
NSData *data = [historyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSLog(@"Array - %@", jsonArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Convert string with emoji to string with unicode like below

```
NSData *data = [strEmoji dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *unicodeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And if you want to show that emoji somewhere then you can convert back in to emoji.

```
NSData *data = [unicodeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *emojiString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```